# Функция Counter (python) не работает для списка со словарем

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dict, counter

Есть список  неуникальных (повторяющихся) кортежей, каждый из которых в одной позиции содержит словарь

Пример одного из кортежей списка:

> ('Проволока Вр-1 ГОСТ 6727-80', {'size': '2,4 мм'}, '45 780', 'руб/т с НДС, свыше 5 тонн', 'abinmetall.ru')

И таких кортежей в этом списке может быть несколько.

Нужно составить словарь, который бы содержал уникальные кортежи (т.е., уникальные элементы списка) в качестве ключа, а в качестве значения - количество повторов этого кортежа в списке.

Например:

> {('Проволока Вр-1 ГОСТ 6727-80', {'size': '2,4 мм'}, '45 780', 'руб/т с НДС, свыше 5 тонн', 'abinmetall.ru'): 7, }

Знаю, что есть функция collections.Counter, которая позволяет генерировать такие словари одним легким вызовом. Но в данном случае эта функция выдает ошибку

> unhashable type: 'dict'

Можете ли подсказать альтернативные способы или функции?

Спасибо

Comment: Можно в исходном наборе данных привести все вложенные словари к хешируемому типу, например к кортежу кортежей - `(('size', '2,4 мм'),)`, тогда можно будет применить Counter.

Comment: Хранить словарь (даже вложенный) в качестве ключа другого словаря действительно не получится. Я бы привёл вложенный словарь к кортежу, тогда данные выглядели бы примерно так: `{('Проволока Вр-1 ГОСТ 6727-80', (('size', '2,4 мм'),), '45 780', 'руб/т с НДС, свыше 5 тонн', 'abinmetall.ru'): 7, }`. Далее, чтобы получить данные в том виде, которые они были изначально, можно к каждому 1-му элементу кортежа применить `dict()` (при условии, что словарь там является всегда первым элементом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя использовать нехешируемые типы для ключа в дикте.

Можно попробовать преобразовать ваш ключ к какому-либо immutable type

Если дикт принципиален для ключа, советую попробовать [frozendict](https://pypi.org/project/frozendict/)

Answer (score 0):

Можно вручную.

Распаковываем элементы из этого кортежа в список и применяем Counter.